# Access an element in an iframe watir

Tags: ruby, iframe, watir

How to access an element inside an external iframe in watir?

```
<iframe src="externalurl">
<html>
<body>
<div class="hello">hello</div>
<form src="externalurl">
<div class="classInFormInIframe"></div>
</form>
</body>
</iframe>
```

How can i access the div inside the form with the external url too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will access the div

```
b.iframe(src: 'externalurl').form(src: 'externalurl').div
```

If you want to trigger any action like `click` then

```
b.iframe(src: 'externalurl').form(src: 'externalurl').div.click
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, the code works but i'm having problems locating the iframe (it doesn't work if i just use `browser.iframe(src: '/accountkit/')`) Any help?  (url is `https:/www.accountkit.com/urlParametersAndMoreParameters`)

Cheers, Chris.

Comment: @ChrisderWahre either use `String` like `'accountkit'` or `RegExp` like `/accountkit/` don't mix them.

Answer (score 1):

The Watir Guide on Frames has just been updated: http://watir.com/guides/frames/

Assuming unique elements can be easily identified, try to nest as little as possible.

```
b.iframe(src: 'externalurl').div(class: 'classInFormInIframe')
```